# complex mapping

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be an open set of $\mathbb{C}$ containing $D=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ and let $f:U\to \mathbb{C}$ be map defined by
$f(z)= e^{iψ} \frac{z-a}{1-\overline{a}z}$ for $a\in D$ and $ψ\in[0,2\pi]$. 
Which of the following statements are true?

1. $|f(e^{iθ})| =1$ for $0<θ<2\pi$ .
2. $f$ maps  $\{z\in\mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ onto itself.
3. $f$ maps  $\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|\le 1\}$ into itself.
4. $f$  is one-one.

I am stuck on this problem . Can anyone help me please.................

Comment: i don't know where to begin..........

Answer (score 1):

If you consider $|a|<1$, the functions of the form $f$ restricted to $D$ describe all of the automorphisms of the unit disk.

If you think about what this means, the boundary of the unit disk (the unit circle) is exactly where $|z|=1$. This should answer problem 1 when you think about the norm of $e^{i \theta}$. In other words, if $|z|=1$, then $|f|=1$.

For 2 and 3, recall that since $f$ restricted to $D$ is an automorphism, it takes domain onto the domain. just think what's in $D$.

For the last part, remember that $f$ takes $D$ onto $D$ and has an inverse since it is a conformal mapping. You can even explicitly state inverse and its domain.

Comment: still not getting sir...........

Comment: Sir,give me some more hints for this question..

Comment: automorphisms of the unit disk??????means............

Comment: @pankaj: It looks like jshin is answering using language and terminology you are unfamiliar with. Please take a look at [our FAQ on homework questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question) to see how you can improve your questions in a way that makes it easier for others to help you.